# How do I listen for scrolling in a ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

The ListView doesn't seem to support the Scroll event.  I need to call a function whenever the list is scrolled; how would I go about that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you need to call a function when the list is scrolled?

If you are changing the items as it's scrolled i would recommend setting the listview to virtual.

Or you could override the listview and do this:

```
public class TestListView : System.Windows.Forms.ListView
{
    private const int WM_HSCROLL = 0x114;
    private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;
    public event EventHandler Scroll;

    protected void OnScroll()
    {

        if (this.Scroll != null)
            this.Scroll(this, EventArgs.Empty);

    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_HSCROLL || m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL)
            this.OnScroll();
    }
}
```

Comment: You must also add WM_MOUSEWHEEL otherwise scrolling with the wheel will be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

it seems the best approach is the brian's solution. However, its only responds to events generated by scrollbars, but no to events from mouse midbuttton.

if you change the conditional:

```
   if (m.Msg == WM_HSCROLL || m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL) 
             this.OnScroll();
```

by:

```
   if (m.Msg == 0x000c2c9) 
             this.OnScroll();
```

now it respods at all scrolling events in listview.

Comment: Would you please tell what C2C9 is ? All Windows Message have a name.