# C#: How do you edit items and subitems in a listview?

Tags: c#, listview

How do you edit items and subitems in a listview? Let's say I have a listview with 3 columns,and subitems,

```
Car Brand | Car Name | Car Year
Ford      | Mustang  | 2000
Dodge     | Charger  | 2007
```

How would I Add items like that to listview and how would I edit let's say the Car Name on which ever row by index[] if I needed to edit at runtime at firing of an event?

Answer (score 29):

If you're looking for "in-place" editing of a `ListView`'s contents (specifically the subitems of a ListView in details view mode), you'll need to implement this yourself, or use a third-party control.

By default, the best you can achieve with a "standard" `ListView` is to set it's `LabelEdit` property to true to allow the user to edit the text of the first column of the `ListView` (assuming you want to allow a free-format text edit).

Some examples (including full source-code) of customized `ListView`'s that allow "in-place" editing of sub-items are:

[C# Editable ListView](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/10/c-editable-listview/)
[In-place editing of ListView subitems](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ListViewCellEditors.aspx)

Comment: The second example is good - just remember that you must add a subitem no matter what - even if it's just blank text or else you get an out of range exception.

Comment: Regarding the second, great, solution - don't forget the control you send to the gui must be added to the control. you can't just send a "new Textbox", will throw a NullException (tries to handle its parent)

Answer (score 21):

I use a hidden textbox to edit all the listview items/subitems. The only problem is that the textbox needs to disappear as soon as any event takes place outside the textbox and the listview doesn't trigger the scroll event so if you scroll the listview the textbox will still be visible.
To bypass this problem I created the Scroll event with this [overrided listview.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372034/how-do-i-listen-for-scrolling-in-a-listview)

Here is my code, I constantly reuse it so it might be help for someone:

```
ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem SelectedLSI;
private void listView2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewHitTestInfo i = listView2.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    SelectedLSI = i.SubItem;
    if (SelectedLSI == null)
        return;

    int border = 0;
    switch (listView2.BorderStyle)
    {
        case BorderStyle.FixedSingle:
            border = 1;
            break;
        case BorderStyle.Fixed3D:
            border = 2;
            break;
    }

    int CellWidth = SelectedLSI.Bounds.Width;
    int CellHeight = SelectedLSI.Bounds.Height;
    int CellLeft = border + listView2.Left + i.SubItem.Bounds.Left;
    int CellTop =listView2.Top + i.SubItem.Bounds.Top;
    // First Column
    if (i.SubItem == i.Item.SubItems[0])
        CellWidth = listView2.Columns[0].Width;

    TxtEdit.Location = new Point(CellLeft, CellTop);
    TxtEdit.Size = new Size(CellWidth, CellHeight);
    TxtEdit.Visible = true;
    TxtEdit.BringToFront();
    TxtEdit.Text = i.SubItem.Text;
    TxtEdit.Select();
    TxtEdit.SelectAll();
}
private void listView2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HideTextEditor();
}
private void listView2_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HideTextEditor();
}
private void TxtEdit_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HideTextEditor();
}
private void TxtEdit_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        HideTextEditor();
}
private void HideTextEditor()
{
    TxtEdit.Visible = false;
    if (SelectedLSI != null)
        SelectedLSI.Text = TxtEdit.Text;
    SelectedLSI = null;
    TxtEdit.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Bumped for very handy C#  close-enough version of Delphi's TStringGrid object. I tweaked this a bit to exclude editing for certain columns, and updating the SQL database behind the listview. Nice!

Comment: perfect code. works like a charm.  to those using, you need to place the txtEdit texbox on top of the listview (assuming the listview is used inside a container) and set the Visible = false

Comment: Nicely done!  Compact solution for a problem I was having.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks very much for sharing this.

Answer (score 9):

Click the items in the list view.
Add a button that will edit the selected items.
Add the code

```
try
{              
    LSTDEDUCTION.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text = txtcarName.Text;
    LSTDEDUCTION.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text = txtcarBrand.Text;
    LSTDEDUCTION.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text = txtCarName.Text;
}
catch{}
```

Comment: This one shows the most basic thing to know regarding changing the data in each ListView (sub)item, which can be used in other different yet somewhat similar scenarios. +1

Answer (score 8):

Sorry, don't have enough rep, or would have commented on [CraigTP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471859/c-how-do-you-edit-items-and-subitems-in-a-listview/1755588#1755588).

I found the solution from the 1st link - [C# Editable ListView](https://web.archive.org/web/20060317101236/http://www.csharphelp.com/archives2/archive341.html), quite easy to use. The general idea is to:

- identify the `SubItem` that was selected and overlay a `TextBox` with the `SubItem`'s text over the `SubItem`
- give this `TextBox` focus
- change `SubItem`'s text to that of `TextBox`'s when `TextBox` loses focus

*What* a workaround for a seemingly simple operation :-|

Answer (score 2):

```
private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    li = listView1.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
    X = e.X;
    Y = e.Y;
}

private void listView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int nStart = X;
    int spos = 0;
    int epos = listView1.Columns[1].Width;
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if (nStart > spos && nStart < epos)
        {
            subItemSelected = i;
            break;
        }

        spos = epos;
        epos += listView1.Columns[i].Width;
    }
    li.SubItems[subItemSelected].Text = "9";
}
```