# Editable ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, listview

I am looking to create an editable ListView in a C# winforms application where a user may double click on a cell in order to change its contents. It would be great if someone could provide my with some guidance and/or an example. I am not looking to use any commercial products.

Comment: Your question might be answered here: [C#: How do you edit items and subitems in a listview?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471859/c-how-do-you-edit-items-and-subitems-in-a-listview

Comment: I would disagree that we should not look at ListView alternatives like DataGridView, ObjectListView or even commercial solutions like [this](http://10tec.com/articles/editable-listview-replacement.aspx), which is cheap enough. Implementing the well-known approach with the textbox editor over ListView items/subitmes has many drawbacks you must solve yourself. For instance, you need to provide a good keyboard interface to edit subitems, the textbox should be scrolled together with the ListView, etc. Using a good 3rd-party solution may save hours of coding, and ultimately, you can even earn more.

Answer (score 20):

You're asking the wrong question :)

A ListView is not the correct control. Use the [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) control. It can be configured to look just like a ListView, but it supports in-place editing of cells.

Comment: That's a matter of opinion. The DataGridView doesn't always fit the use scenario or provide the required look-and-feel. However, it is a possible alternative, depending on the goals of the OP.

Comment: You can't do grouped views with the DataGridView. Plus a host of other features that only a ListView supports.

Comment: Took me a minute, but, uh, yeah ... "List*VIEW*" ... view -not- edit. Funny thing, though, DataGridVIEW lets one *EDIT*. Hmmmm.

Answer (score 6):

An [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net) will do exactly that and much more. It is a wrapper around a normal .NET ListView. It is open source.

Its website has a [Getting Started](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/gettingStarted.html) to help you begin, as well as a whole page devoted to [cell editing](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/cellEditing.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. This custom control looks interesting, but may be overkill for what I'm trying to do. I shall experiment with it nonetheless.

Comment: Actually, it's not a custom control really. It's just a helpful wrapper around a plain ListView. But we won't tell anyone that :)

Comment: It also might not be a suitable licence for all projects (as it appears to be under GPLv3)

Comment: editing is not good with this lib. when i press tab its so slow to open next control. cound't find a fix for that.

Answer (score 1):

From the sounds of it, you might want to consider using the DataGridView instead.

[DataGridView (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the listview's DoubleClick event, and when it is called, you would open a new form where the user would enter a new value for the selected item. Then when the user has pressed ok, you would edit the value of the specific item to what the user has entered.

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView is your friend
SourceGrid is alternative

Answer (score 0):

You could use a DataTemplate to specify that the column contains a textbox (if editable) or a textblock (if not editable) then bind the textbox to the class property from your Source Object Collection that is bound to your listview's itemsource.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="NameHeader">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="NameCell">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="lvwList" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SourceObjectCollection}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource NameHeader}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource NameCell}" Width="140" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Nick Hanshaw

Comment: Welcome to SO, Nick. This is a good answer but unfortunately the question is tagged `winforms`, not `wpf`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a DataGridView.

Not only can you edit a cell, but if you declare a generic List where T is the class you want to display in the grid,  you can set the DataSource=that list and as you edit the gridview you are actually editing the List  automagically!

Answer (score -1):

maybe this could help you:

[msdn:How to create a ListView with Editable Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745183.aspx)

Comment: This is a WPF article. Is that what is desired, or are we looking at straight WinForms here? The tags indicate WinForms.

Answer (score -1):

I recently encountered this issue. After taking the hint from Simon Gillbee that it is possible to configure DataGridView to appear much like ListView, I searched for a sensible solution to accomplish just that. The following code worked well for me. [Source here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/141aef69-b7c4-412f-a067-bc4bce011167/).

```
class GridLineDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    public GridLineDataGridView()
    {
        this.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        int rowHeight = this.RowTemplate.Height;

        int h = this.ColumnHeadersHeight + rowHeight * this.RowCount;
        int imgWidth = this.Width - 2;
        Rectangle rFrame = new Rectangle(0, 0, imgWidth, rowHeight);
        Rectangle rFill = new Rectangle(1, 1, imgWidth - 2, rowHeight);
        Rectangle rowHeader = new Rectangle(2, 2, this.RowHeadersWidth - 3, rowHeight);

        Pen pen = new Pen(this.GridColor, 1);

        Bitmap rowImg = new Bitmap(imgWidth, rowHeight);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rowImg);
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, rFrame);
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor), rFill);
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush
           (this.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor), rowHeader);

        int w = this.RowHeadersWidth - 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < this.ColumnCount; j++)
        {
            g.DrawLine(pen, new Point(w, 0), new Point(w, rowHeight));
            w += this.Columns[j].Width;
        }

        int loop = (this.Height - h) / rowHeight;
        for (int j = 0; j < loop + 1; j++)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(rowImg, 1, h + j * rowHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

Just inherit from `DataGridView` and override the `OnPaint` method.

You can change the various properties of the control to suit your needs and preferences.

For those who need assistance with incorporating a custom control into their project look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h62478z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: The example is incomplete. For those new to WPF, where do you put the new DataGrid?

Comment: @CJohnson: This question is about WinForms and **not** WPF. Please check the question tag and context.