# Updating a listview subitem manually C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

First time poster here.

I'm working a little app that populates a list view columns with the properties of a media file. I have 4 columns with the 4th being for manually added comments via a text box. The text box will let me add comments to an empty row but it won't allow me to select a specific row to add a comment to such as one that has been populated with data. Any thoughts.

Here is my code for populating the row with a comment:

```
private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    item.SubItems.Add("");
    item.SubItems.Add("");
    item.SubItems.Add(TB_Comment.Text);
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
    TB_Comment.Clear();
    TB_title.Focus();                       

}
```

And here is a screenshot of the issue I'm having.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeMfu.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miDN7.png)

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

Comment: Hi there, you're going about this the wrong way. A `ListView` is for displaying, you'll need to use a `DataGridView` for what you're trying to achieve. See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808588/editable-listview

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. I thought that might be the case from the research i've done but wondered if it's achieve in Listview.

Comment: The 1st column only can be edited. And you can change the display order.