# How to edit subitems in listview

Tags: vb.net, listview, listviewitem

Does anyone know how you can edit the subitems of the listView in the same way as you can the items text labels (this first item in the row)?

Setting the LabelEdit property to true only effect the main item labels of the row not any of the subitems.

```
        'listview.SelectedItems(0).BeginEdit()
```

The above line can only edit first column of the listview.

Comment: You can't.  Take a look at DataGridView.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: How do you edit items and subitems in a listview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471859/c-how-do-you-edit-items-and-subitems-in-a-listview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listview doesn't have that capability. One way to accomplish this is to bring up a small form with all the subitems of the listview item in textboxes or a gridview so they can be edited.