# How to type in listview columns

Tags: vb6

I want to type in list view column

ListView

```
ID Name

001 Rajan
002 Sajan
003 Vijayan
....
```

I want to edit in the listview itself, I want to change the name.

I want to change the text in listview column itself.

How to do this..

Need vb6 code help

Comment: Did someone ring the "give me teh codez" bell or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to edit subitems in listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294640/how-to-edit-subitems-in-listview)

Comment: I tried to flag this for moderator attention because I'm getting tired of reading these, but it didn't work (dialog said I had to include at least 10 characters even though I included 100+). Has anyone else tried to flag these posts? This has been going on far too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listview doesn't support editing of the sub items.

You will either need to change to use a normal grid control, or place your own textbox on top of the listview and set the text/style as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear. But I will answer as best as I can.

First, I assume that you have a ListView that contains values that you want to print out.
If that is the case, here is the code that would do that:

```
For i=0 to ListView.Count -1
    Print ListView.Item(i)

Next
```

As for changing the values that already exists in a ListView, you can type

```
ListView.item(2) = "New Value"
```