# C# ListView - Programatically editing column entries

Tags: c#, listview, edit, multiple-columns, subitem

I'm using a **ListView** with two columns.

To add new items (into column zero) I'm using:

```
listView1.Items.Add("Hello")
```

This results in *Hello* being present in the column with the lowest index.
However, I'd also like to add in **line numbers**.

I'm trying this with:

```
        for (int c = 0; c < listView1.Items.Count; c++)
        {
            listView1.Items[c].SubItems.Clear();
            listView1.Items[c].SubItems.Add(c.ToString());
        }
```

The problem, I believe, lies with the main item(s) being cleared even though I'm just attemping to `clear()` the subitems (i.e. the entry in the second column).

**So essentially my question is:**
How do I individually edit column entries to be able to display the lines/row numbers?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean there, sorry. The ListView control is what I'm using from the toolbox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471859/c-how-do-you-edit-items-and-subitems-in-a-listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471859/c-how-do-you-edit-items-and-subitems-in-a-listview)

Comment: Its usually better to post the way you solve your problem as an answer instead of putting it in the question.

Comment: His answer is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First item (index 0) in SubItems is actually main item in left column.

If you already added sub item like this `listViewItem.SubItems.Add(string.Empty);` then you can edit that sub item like this:

```
    for (int c = 0; c < listView1.Items.Count; c++)
    {
        listView1.Items[c].SubItems[1].Text = c.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: A `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` occurs when I attempt to access `SubItems[1]`.

Comment: If you didn't added sub item then you need to add it first. I assumed you were added any because you were clearing them.

Comment: It doesn't show up when I use `SubItems[1]`. It shows up when I use `SubItems[0]`.

Comment: If you didn't added any sub items like this ```listViewItem.SubItems.Add(string.Empty);``` then there won't be any subitems at index 1.

Answer (score -1):

I may have solved it...

It may be that once a `SubItem` is added, the main item is moved to `SubItem[0]`.

The following code seems to be working for me, but I'm not sure if a better way exists.

```
        for (int c = 0; c < listView1.Items.Count; c++)
        {
            listView1.Items[c].SubItems[0].Text = listView1.Items[c].Text;
            listView1.Items[c].SubItems.Add(c.ToString());
            listView1.Items[c].SubItems[1].Text = c.ToString();
        }
```