# Add more items to same Row and same column in listview

Tags: c#

I know how to add/delete items but I don't know how to add more items to the same field (same row and same column). I want whenever I click a button, an item is added to same selected row but not to new row in the listView.
I uploaded a photo you can check to see what I exactly mean.

[image]

Comment: \n is the escape character to make a new line, try adding strings together with \n between them

Comment: Please show us what you've got so far.  Otherwise we'll just be guessing, and I for one am terrible at guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Consider looking at ObjectListView or DataGridView instead of what you are currently. It may be more flexible to your needs.

Your question is somewhat unclear. Clearly you are using listView and you have columns and rows resulting in a cell / box / grid location. I gather that, after its initial creation, you wish to append or alter the data at that location.

To get to the point: Multi-line text within a given 'cell' is not supported (as best I can tell). The picture you have shown is likely a custom object or something similar to a listView, but different (such as a ObjectListView). Or perhaps a picture.

```
listView2.Items[0].SubItems[4].Text = "123\nabc"; //Doesn't add a proper newline like a normal string

listView2.Items[0].SubItems[4].Text = "123\rabc"; //Doesn't add a proper return carriage like a normal string

listView2.Items[0].SubItems[4].Text = "123\r\nabc"; //Doesn't add a proper newline like a normal string
```

I am assuming you are using the details view

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
```

First adding your headers, listView1.Columns.Add(text, width);

```
listView1.Columns.Add(First Name", 50);
listView1.Columns.Add("Middle Name", 100);
listView1.Columns.Add("Last Name", 100);
```

You then add data to the listView. However, this is not done directly. You build a listViewITEM then add that item to the list view.

```
string[] row = new string[3];
row[0] = "john";
row[1] = "someone";
row[2] = "doe";

ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(row);

listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

listView1.SelectedItems[#].SubItems[#].Text = "string" + "\n" + "string2";

CrazyPaste suggested adding a row, which could be practical and is something you often see with listViews.
However, If you choose to add or "redo" the rows, be sure to remove any old information before inputting new information to avoid duplicates.
Taken from the popup within visual studio 2013 pro

```
listView1.Items.RemoveAt(int index)
listView1.Items.Insert(int index, string key, string text, int imageIndex)
```

OR

```
listView1.Items.Clear(); //Clears all items
```

then

```
//Add populate logic here
```

Two arrays or a multidimensional array in a loop would be effective if you wish to populate the listview in that manner.

To achieve this programmatically, you could...

```
        listView2 = new ListView();
        listView2.View = View.Details;
        listView2.Location = new Point(50, 50);
        listView2.Size = new Size(400, 100);

        this.Controls.Add(listView2);

        listView2.Columns.Add("AAA");
        listView2.Columns.Add("BBB");
        listView2.Columns.Add("CCC");
        listView2.Columns.Add("DDD");
        listView2.Columns.Add("EEE");

        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();
        item1.Text = "0"; //The way to properly set the first piece of a data in a row is with .Text
        item1.SubItems.Add("1"); //all other row items are then done with .SubItems
        item1.SubItems.Add("2");
        item1.SubItems.Add("3");
        item1.SubItems.Add("");
        item1.SubItems.Add("");

        ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem();
        item2.Text = "00";
        item2.SubItems.Add("11");
        item2.SubItems.Add("22");
        item2.SubItems.Add("33");
        item2.SubItems.Add("");
        item2.SubItems.Add("");

        ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem();
        item3.Text = "000";
        item3.SubItems.Add("111");
        item3.SubItems.Add("222");
        item3.SubItems.Add("333");
        item3.SubItems.Add("");
        item3.SubItems.Add("");

        //item1.SubItems.Clear();
        //item1.SubItems.RemoveAt(1);
        listView2.Items.Add(item1);
        listView2.Items.Add(item2);
        listView2.Items.Add(item3);
        //listView2.Items.Insert(2, item1); //0 here is the row. Increasing the number, changes which row you are writing data across


        listView2.Items[0].SubItems[4].Text = "123\rabc";
```

To 'update' the information:

```
listView1.Items.Clear();
listView1.Items.Add(item1);
listView1.Items.Add(item2);
```

...etc

NOTES:

- I was not able to get .Insert to work with subitems.
- If you already inserted a listViewItem, You cannot insert an item
  without first removing it
- SubItems are not automatically created to fill empty space. Commands like 'listView2.Items[0].SubItems[4].Text' will not work with null/non-existent SubItems

Comment: hi Branden, thank you for you reply. yes I used listView and I have columns and rows resulting in a cell where I want to insert a multi line in same cell . I tried the \n but didnt work. I tried your code but didnt work. so you are saying multiline is not supported? do you know any other tool which can do what i want?  please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much to go on.  But this adds a new row:

```
string[] row = { "1", "snack", "2.50" };
var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row); 
listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
```

Here's a post discussing how to update an existing listitem:
[C#: How do you edit items and subitems in a listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471859/c-how-do-you-edit-items-and-subitems-in-a-listview)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply. I tried your code, this code just adds new items to new row :( but not to the same row as i wanted, so please try if you can help, thank you

Comment: Is this winforms datagridview?

Comment: No, it is a listview.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. after I searched the internet for ages, it turned out that listView does not support text wrap. so instead I used DataGridView. thank you for your help