# How to edit items in a listview

Tags: c#, listview, edit

I want to be able to edit the items that I have added to my listview.

The listview items were added through a textbox, datetimepicker, and a combobox.

The listview has three columns. What I want is: When I click on the listview item, (the listview selects all the columns) and then click on the edit button, then the textbox is replaced with column one, the datetimepicker is replaced with the date of column 2, and the combobox is replaced with column 3.

Then I can edit the textbox, date, or the combobox items and when I click the save button, then the listview item is updated.

Comment: ListView supports only editing the Text of the Item, not any Subitems. To edit these you need to code a suitable  overlay edit control over them..

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: You may want to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471859/c-how-do-you-edit-items-and-subitems-in-a-listview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to use separate edit controls and buttons to update there is no need to overlay the listview subitems with controls.

Here is example code to load the controls from the 1st selected item and to update that `Item` in the `ListView`:

```
    private void lv_edit_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lv_edit.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
        {
            var lvi = lv_edit.SelectedItems[0];
            tb_col1.Text = lvi.SubItems[0].Text;
            date_col2.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(lvi.SubItems[1].Text);
            combo_col3.SelectedIndex = combo_col3.FindStringExact(lvi.SubItems[2].Text);
        }
    }

    private void cb_updateItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lv_edit.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
        {
            var lvi = lv_edit.SelectedItems[0];
            lvi.SubItems[0].Text = tb_col1.Text;
            lvi.SubItems[1].Text = date_col2.Value.ToString("dddd, dd. MMMM yyyy");
            lvi.SubItems[2].Text = combo_col3.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Note that `SubItems[0].Text` is the same as `Items[0].Text`.

Also note that the code assumes that all items have all three fields and their values are all valid, ie that the conversion and the find will work.