# How to add subitems to a specific row/index in a listView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I am trying to make a soundboard program that plays a user added sound when either the play button is pressed or an optionally set hotkey is pressed. I would like to display the hotkey next to the sound name in the list view. But I do not know how to add/edit a subitem with only the index of the selected row.

I have seen people do this:

```
 ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
 lvi.SubItems.Add("SubItem");
 listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
```

but it is not helpful because I cannot create a different variable for each row(I think) because it is inputted by the user.

This is the result I am hoping to get:

[image]

and this is what I have got so far:

[image]

Edit: I have worked out how to add the Items:

```
    private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string fileName in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
        {
            var item = new ListViewItem(fileName);
            item.SubItems.Add("Alt+Shift+Numpad1");
            lvAudio.Items.Add(item);
            listBoxAudio.Items.Add(fileName);
        }
    }
```

But I am still not sure how to add/edit a hotkey on the selected row later on while the program is running.

Comment: Hi maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471859/c-how-do-you-edit-items-and-subitems-in-a-listview

Comment: DataGridView are much more easy to use imho (also without database source)

Comment: @hammerthea I tried this:  `try
   {              
    LSTDEDUCTION.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text = txtcarName.Text;
    LSTDEDUCTION.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text = txtcarBrand.Text;
    LSTDEDUCTION.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text = txtCarName.Text;
}
catch{}` But it doesn't work. If I remove the try-catch I get `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.'
`

Comment: You always should test the index you want to access. If it doesn't exist, add it. Do not abuse try/catch for 'crash-testing' things you expect to fail!! - Why do you think you can't write `..Subitems.Add(textbox.Text)` ???

Comment: @Taw I have edited the post

Comment: `if (lvi.SubItems.Count >= 1)  lvi.SubItems[1].Text = newText` ?

Comment: @TaW I would have already added multiple Items using that object, so most of them wouldn't be associated with it.

Comment: Of course you need to pick the one the user wants to edit; maybe `if (listview1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) ListViewItem lvi = listview1.SelectedItems[0] `.

Comment: Btw: You did set the LV to View=Details and did add 2 columns, right?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the items and subitems, treat them like collections and user their indexes to get to them:

```
if (lvAudio.SelectedItems.Count > 0) 
{
      var file = lvAudio.SelectedItems[0];
      if(file.SubItems.Count > 1)
      {
          var shortcut = file.SubItems[1];
          shortcut.Text = "New Shortcut";
      }
}
```