# Use ListView for configure Files

Tags: c#, listview

I am developing a program to install server files of a game.

The whole part of the installation has already been done successfully. Now it's time to configure all the available options of the game.

What I want to do is a ListView with two columns, for example (Config and Value)
and from there edit the necessary values to then insert them into the game something like this:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea of how to do it? I was intent on making the second column editable because I could not do it. If there is another alternative it will be taken.

Comment: _Does anyone have an idea of how to do it?_ The idea should be coming from you...also the code... we maybe can help you fix your issues

Comment: what application type: is this winforms, WPF? how do you want to save it? creating an XML, CSV, plain text? What have you tried? Your question is too broad, not suitable for SO and please don't paste images.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'd love to close this as a duplicate but didn't find a question/answer that really fits..

Comment: Is a WinForm! Sorry for the image. I have the idea but i dont know how to do that.. i know how to insert Complet listview in a file but i need specific Line. in specific files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is simple, as long as you only need **one** editable column:

- Make the LV's 1st column editable: `Listview1.LabelEdit = true;`
- Set the 2nd column's `Displayindex = 0` effectively making it 1st internally.

Now you can still only edit column1 but see it in 2nd place.

If you need more columns you need either a more involved [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471859/c-how-do-you-edit-items-and-subitems-in-a-listview) or you could (and imo sholud) go for a `DataGridView`.

Comment: Thanks, Now, how i do for insert a specific value of ListView in a file?
For example. in my list view i have Experience 1 and y in my file y have a line like 
Experience = 1. How i can to insert some like that?

Comment: You mean how to write a file? And how to read it? File.ReadAllLines and FileWriteAllLines are simple and pulling the listviewitwems/subitems from the lv is also not hard..: save: `var lines = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(x => x.SubItems[1].Text + "=" + x.Text).ToArray();
  File.WriteAllLines(@"config.txt", lines);` load: `var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"config.txt");
listView1.Items.Clear();
foreach (string l in lines)
{
    var p = l.Split('=');
    var lvi = listView1.Items.Add(p[1]);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(p[0]);
}`

Comment: It is easier to write/read all values in one go. To change specific lines is a bit harder, usually makes little sense and clearly is a separate question.

Comment: Great!! your code work! The problem is than the file have so much //////////////// or ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; separators and spaces, and this cause crash in application.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains us both a little reputation.. - Of course nobody can help you with your data, nor code we don't see. Try asking your best friend for help: It is the debugger.. And if the issue persists you can ask a new question. Try to read the help pages before you do so you won't get downvoted so much..!!

Comment: Thanks! :)You have your checkmark