# Edit listview item based on click_event c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, search, replace

i have created a listview

```
        ListView ListView1 = new ListView();
        ListView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        ListView1.Name = "ListView1";
        ListView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(280, 300);
        ListView1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        ListView1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        ListView1.View = View.Details;
        ListView1.GridLines = true;
        ListView1.FullRowSelect = true;
        ListView1.Columns.Add("ProductName", 100);
        ListView1.Columns.Add("Quantity", 100);
        ListView1.Columns.Add("Price", 100);
```

and i add items to it using the following code :

```
b.Click += (s, e) => {
                    string[] arr = new string[4];
                    ListViewItem itm;
                    arr[0] = b.Text;
                    arr[1] = x.ToString();
                    arr[2] = price;
                    itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
                    ListView1.Items.Add(itm);
                    x++;
                    };
```

b is an auto generated button, what i want to achieve is simple the variable x will increment with value 1 everytime i click on the button b, and x indicate the Quantity.
What i want:
when ever i click on the button b, the Quantity will change for the current item that has the Column["Productname"]=b.Text
What im getting:
the Quantity change but the item gets reinserted so i want to check if the item does exist first(based on Column["Productname"]) and if it does w the Quantity gets incremented by 1.

[image_to_help_understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT6Ny.png)

More details: im sorry if this is getting too long, but im simply having a number of auto generated buttons and every button represents a product, when the user click on a product it gets added to the list ( to buy it later) and if the client clicks the same product n times, the Quantity should became Quantity=n without the item being added another time. thanks all and sorry for the long post.

Comment: [Listview has a method called FindItemWithText.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.finditemwithtext?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thank you but, FinditemwithText wont replace the value and thats what i need

Comment: I should have read your question better. I thought you could find the existing item with FindItemWithText and if so then bump the qty [using edit in place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4941088/3585500).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i found the solution! i was using a While loop when i shouldn't, i made things harder... but lucky i figured it out:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poking values into the UI is not a good design. I have these changes from my previous comments. Use a BindingList, public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged, and replace the ListView with a DataGridView. This just makes life a whole lot easier and the code so simple. Creating ListBoxItems on your own is NOT a good way of doing things.
BTW: to find a product you just use a LINQ query on the ProductCollection. No searching the UI.